# Unit conversion from mm to m in text file with text and numbers

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl

I'm trying to convert the following style text file from mm to m (i.e., divide all numbers by 1000). It's made up of a regular pattern and contains text as well as numbers.

I have managed to solve (eventually) using python, it's a bit rough and ready but it completes the task. Any suggestions/improvements would be greatly appreciated.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import linecache
from io import StringIO

myfile = "file"
results = open("results.txt","w")

for i in range(1,50000):
    line = linecache.getline(myfile,i)
    if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', line):
        results.write(line)    
    elif line.isspace():
        results.write(str(line))
    elif re.search('[-]', line):
        results.write(str(line))
    else:
        c = StringIO(line)
        data = np.loadtxt(c)
        a = np.array(data)
        c = a / 1000
        d = str(c).replace('[','').replace(']','')
        results.write(str(d)+'\n')
results.close()
```

the file is like so:

```
add
tube
3033303.0 2998206.95111 106180.1625
60.325 6222.60621
y
0.0 0.0
0.0
add
cube
3027189.24332 3032175.78955 114508.75
168.9 6170.76909
y
0.0 0.0
0.0
```

Desired outcome would be;

```
add
tube
3033.3030 2998.20695111 106.1801625
0.060325 6.22260621
y
0.0 0.0
0.0
add
cube
3027.18924332 3032.17578955 114.50875
0.1689 6.17076909
y
0.0 0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Stack OverFlow is not a code writing serivce

Comment: 1. open the file, 2. for each line, 3. if the first character is not a digit, copy the line to output, 4. otherwise split the line, convert each piece to float, divide by 1000, convert back to a line of text, write to output. It should take you about 6 minutes to write and test.

Comment: i'm new to coding so didn't really know where to start. so far i've tried to read the file in, remove text and blank spaces and convert to a list then divide but wasn't making any progress. apologies if it comes across as 'please write this code for me', wasn't intended - just needed some pointers. thanks, hugh, i'll try that.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to user comments (even after getting shut down) instead of just adding a whiney line explaining why your question should be reopened, as so many people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy in perl

```
perl -pe 's-(\d+.?\d*)-($1/1000)-ge' file

add
tube
3033.303 2998.20695111 106.1801625
0.060325 6.22260621
y
0 0
0
add
cube
3027.18924332 3032.17578955 114.50875
0.1689 6.17076909
y
0 0
0
```